# Merge two numeric arrays in one using php

Tags: php, arrays, merge, numeric

I have 2 arrays

```
array:2 [▼
         0 => "folder1/first"
         1 => "folder2/second"
]

array:2 [▼
         0 => "scheme.pdf"
         1 => "example.pdf"
]
```

I have to merge these arrays, so I get 1 array with such construction:

```
array:2 [▼
         "folder1/first" => "scheme.pdf"
         "folder2/second" => "example.pdf"
]
```

I assume, that I have to use these commands `array_map`, `array_merge_recursive`
As I understood, second command is functional only with non-numeric keys. Then, all numeric keys in both arrays have to be converted to strings. 
Can someone tell me or even show a part of code how can I merge these two arrays according to my needs. 
The example is simple, but I never did this one before. I did search for the answer, but all of them were too complicated to understand.

Comment: So did you have a try at doing this yourself? If so show us

Comment: Try  `array_combine($a1, $a2)`

Comment: Why not start by doing a simple `foreach` over the arrays and building a new array in the format you want. THEN try and get clever with the PHP built in functions

Comment: @Thefourthbird worked perfectly! Just 1 row of code and no need of complex functions. BTW I didn't know this command. Thank you!